# Array aggregation in Exasol

Tags: sql, array-agg, exasol

Use case is fairly straightforward. In postgres I can aggregate values from a `GROUP BY` into an array:

```sql
select
  customer,
  array_agg(product_name) as items
from transactions
group by customer

customer      items
-----------------------------------------------------------
john          [salad, pizza, beer, diapers, pasta, cheese]
joe           [cheese, beef, yoghurt, milk, water]
```

In Exasol, from the [documentation page on aggregate functions](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/aggregatefunctions.htm), I can only see `GROUP_CONCAT` which merges all values from `items` above into a comma-separated string.

Is it possible to get these values in a proper array instead of in a string?

Answer (score 2):

Could following help you where just concatenating the '[' and ']' characters

```
SELECT 
customer, concat('[',group_concat(product_name),']') as items 
FROM transactions group by customer;
```